# runtime error 91 with Win8

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an VBA project in Excel, that was working with win XP and win7. When I try to run it on win8 I have an runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.
here is the sub that causes the error:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_UnLock()
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'this line throws error
        Sheet.Unprotect Password:=myPassword
    Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I don't have "option explicit" on top of the code.
changing from ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets to Sheets doesn't solved the problem, but I found something interesting - my code works fine when i save file with code to local HD, but it gives runtime error 91 when it is opened from server. How is that possible?? 
I really need to have file on a server.

Comment: Is it for Excel 2013??

Comment: try to chagne `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Do you have an `Option Explicit` at the top of your module? Maybe you need to dimension the `Sheet` variable before using it in a loop. What about `myPassword` variable? Where is it declared? Also, try replacing `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` with just `Sheets`

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code? Is `Sheet` Nothing?

Comment: by the way, excel is 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 91 occurs because an object is not set so I would make sure that the ActiveWorkbook does have sheets added to it. You may want to give this a try and see if it still throws an error.

```
Sub Worksheet_UnLock()
    Dim s as Worksheet

    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        s.Unprotect Password:=myPassword
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, that worked.
Can you explain, why my old code was working on the HDD but was not working on the network drive?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually not sure why yours was working on your hard drive. My guess was `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` was causing the problem as it has given me problems in the past. I have since used `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` and haven't had any problems.